# How do I interpret this bugsense crash report?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, bugsense

I have an app which occasionally kicks users out after they've logged in and had it minimized for a few hours.  It happens randomly with no preference for a specific device or os version.  Here's the bugsense crash log

```
Error Message

data parameter is nil


Where

0x84000 +


Short Stacktrace

0   CoreFoundation 0x2e7cee83 + 130

1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x38b2b6c7 objc_exception_throw + 38

2   CoreFoundation 0x2e7cedc5 + 0

3   Foundation 0x2f156be7 + 66

4   MEMetrics 0x0009820d 0x84000 + 82445

5   Foundation 0x2f10947f + 54

Affected App Versions

2.0

Affected SDKs

7.0.4

Details (last occurence of error)


OS   iOS 7.0.4

App Version  2.0

Device   iPhone5,3

Country  US

wifi_on  1

user_id user6@test.com

locale   en_US

sdk_version  3.4

mobile_net_on    0

jailbreak    0

log_data     {u'ms_from_start': 42804}

internal_version     2.0

carrier  Verizon

build_uuid   5310A8F9-6F2B-3D2D-B7E8-9C5F9621FF3C

gps_on   1

execname     MEMetrics
```

It seems to appear in no specific file.

Comment: It means nothing until you symbolicate it.

Comment: It involves using the `.dSYM` files from your release build to make sense of those numbers.  There are a couple of ways of doing with an Apple-generated crash log, but I've not idea with bug sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sense of these lines by uploading DSYM files in the Bugsense settings for a project.

> Try going to a Project then Settings -> DSYMs (Here it explains how
>   you should zip and upload a DSYM file from an xarchive)

These are symbol definition files that help a crash report generator understand the lines of code that correspond to the information coded in that report. Upload latest DSym files each time you upload a binary for distribution or to app store (At least that is what I do, if someone knows of a better way or frequency on which we should upload these files please let us know)